# Openlayers ol is not defined

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

Here is what I'm importing:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import 'ol/ol.css';
import ExtentInteraction from 'ol/interaction/Extent';
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import { OSM } from 'ol/source';
import { Tile as TileLayer } from 'ol/layer';
import { shiftKeyOnly } from 'ol/events/condition';
import { Stroke, Style } from 'ol/style';
import { Control, defaults as defaultControls } from 'ol/control';
```

Here is my usage of ol that is being flagged:

```
    const controls = map.getControls();
    controls.forEach((control) => {
        console.log(control instanceof ol.control.Zoom);
    });
```

The error is that ol is undefined. Is this an issue with my import or is there another reference that needs to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import [`Zoom`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_Zoom-Zoom.html) also from `ol/control`:

```
import { Control, Zoom, defaults as defaultControls } from 'ol/control';

...

controls.forEach((control) => {
  console.log(control instanceof Zoom);
});
```